# Merge multiple canvas in one (to export it) using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webcam

I'm in a situation where I generate multiple canvas (~200) where I draw an image snapped from the user webcam (experimentation of the "photo finish" technique).

I have to export those canvas as a simple jpeg as shown in the following image.

[image: multiple canvas as "stripes" into one]

You can also see how it should visually look like (multiple stripe as multiple canvas, those I have to export as one and only Jpg).

[image]

Any idea or direction of how proceed?

Thanks in advance!

AW.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). It accepts an other canvas as bitmap source (first param).

So you'll need to

- determine the size of your final canvas
- determine the position of every smaller canvases
- draw these

```js
// sizes of each strip
var width = 10;
var height = 200;
// we'll store each 'strip' canvas in an Array
var strips = [];
for(var i = 0; i<60; i++) {
  // fill the Array
  strips.push(makeStrip());
  // populate the doc
  container.appendChild(strips[i]);
}

// our merging canvas
var merger = document.createElement('canvas');
merger.width = width * 60; // sum of widths
merger.height = height;
var ctx = merger.getContext('2d');
// iterate through all our strips
strips.forEach(function drawToMerger(small, i) {
  // simply draw at index * width
  ctx.drawImage(small, i * width, 0);
});
// export
merger.toBlob(function(blob) {
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});

// Strip builder
function makeStrip() {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = width;
   canvas.height = height;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,canvas.height);
   grad.addColorStop(0, randColor());
   grad.addColorStop(1, randColor());
   ctx.fillStyle = grad;
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   return canvas;
}
function randColor() { 
  return '#' + (Math.random()).toString(16).substr(2,6);
}
```

```css
#container{white-space:nowrap}
canvas:hover{opacity:.7}
img{border: 3px solid #00FF00}
```

```html
Strips:
<div id="container"></div>
Merged Image:
<img id="img">
```

But note that you may also want to work on a single canvas from the beginning, it would free up some memory.